# Does laser trap atom cooling change the electron shell levels?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, energy-conservation, orbitals

Do the electron orbits change during the cooling of the atom in a laser trap? When cooling down, do the electrons come closer to the nucleus of the atom or do they move away?
Or do the electrons leave the orbits because the atom's energy has changed?

https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3439

What I understand in this publication in atom Ep is changed (eq 1.).
In figs 4, 5 and 6 the smoothing should not occur with quantization. I see there Is no quantization in energy loosing.
I conclude that the electron shells are shifting and that there are no electron jumps in some iterations but energy is lost. Do I interpret it correctly?

Comment: Photons are absorbed and re-emitted. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: I rebuilt the question. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Given that the laser wavelength does not need to change during the cooling, the answer is, no, the electron orbits don't change.

Comment: @JonCuster According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus_cooling , "Repeated cycles of this nature convert kinetic energy to potential energy, and this potential energy is lost via the photon emitted during optical pumping." Ep is changed, so electron distance to core also should be changed?

Comment: Why Ep is changed? It is because proton energy is changed or elektron energy is changed? What I understand this that the laser trap change the proton energy.